# SAP DBTech JDBC: [275]: aggregate function not allowed:

Tags: sql, aggregate, hana

Can you please guys advice me with the query for this , i have the error aggregate function not allowed when using SUM , the query in SAP HANA SQL

```
 IF :object_type = '13'  AND (:transaction_type='A' or :transaction_type='U')
THEN
BEGIN 
update OINV set OINV."U_TotalDiscountLines" = SUM(INV1."PriceBefDi" - INV1."Price") from INV1 , OINV where INV1."DocEntry"=:list_of_cols_val_tab_del AND OINV."DocEntry"=:list_of_cols_val_tab_del ;
END;
END IF;
```

Comment: Hello , any help ?

Comment: This UPDATE command is not valid SQL - what is SUM() supposed to do here?

Comment: i just want to update the value of the field with the SUM of the two column in the query , how can i do it ?

Comment: But your sum contains a substraction of two columns? Although I don't really understand the question and the intended outcome of the SQL statement, the answer to your question is most probably the usage of the `MERGE INTO` statement. https://help.sap.com/docs/HANA_CLOUD_DATABASE/c1d3f60099654ecfb3fe36ac93c121bb/3226201f95764a57810dd256c9524d56.html?locale=en-US

Comment: For exemple : INV1."PriceBefDi" as two value : 140 and 100 , and INV1."Price" as this : 100 and 100 . The SUM of this two substraction will be (140 - 100 and 100 - 100 ) = 40 , that i need to insert in the column : OINV."U_TotalDiscountLines" . That the result that i except . I will check the usage of MERGE INTO